# Parentheses check in Java

Tags: java, arrays, stack

I am trying to see if my equation balances out in case of parentheses. But i am having trouble with the equation, `x=(1+2))+3`. It is always valid even though it is not. Any help?

```
public boolean checkEquation(String infix){
    for(int j=0;j<infix.length();j++){    // loop until the end of the line for a string (expression)
    // Check for parentheses
        if( infix.charAt(j)=='('){
            operatorStack.push(infix.charAt(j)); // push the parentheses to stack
        } 
        // Check for braces
        else if( infix.charAt(j)=='[' ){
            operatorStack.push(infix.charAt(j)); // push the braces to stack
        }
        // Check for bracket
        else if( infix.charAt(j)=='{' ){
            operatorStack.push(infix.charAt(j)); // push the bracket to stack
        }

        /* for reverse cases */
        // Check for reverse parentheses
        else if( infix.charAt(j)==')' ){
            if(operatorStack.isStackEmpty()){
                System.out.println(operatorStack.pop());
                return false;
            }
            if(operatorStack.peek()!='('){
                System.out.println(operatorStack.pop());
                return false;
            }
        }
        // Check for reverse braces
        else if( infix.charAt(j)==']' ){
            if(operatorStack.isStackEmpty()){
                return false;
            }
            if(operatorStack.peek()!='['){
                return false;
            }
        }
        // Check for reverse bracket
        else if( infix.charAt(j)=='}' ){
            if(operatorStack.isStackEmpty()){
                return false;
            }
            if(operatorStack.peek()!='{'){
                return false;
            }
        }
            // ignore other characters for now
    } // close for loop

    return operatorStack.isStackEmpty();

} // end of checkEquation method
```

Comment: I suggest you learn to use the debugger in your IDE. With a little bit of effort, you should be able to track down where the problem(s) are in your code.

Comment: If you use `peek()` you leave the character inside the stack. That way the second `)` also uses the first `(` to do the checking. You should use `pop()` instead.

Comment: code-apprentice: tried with debugger, but couldn't come up with a solution.

Comment: Tom- i tried with pop(), doesn't work either only for the above expression

Comment: Then post an example for which expression it doesn't work.

Comment: maybe you would like to see above ? -tom

Comment: I see there one expression and you said the change works for that, but not for others.

Comment: It doesn't work for this expression. works for other expressions. any help?

Comment: Well then you're doing something else wrong. I've tested your code with my suggested change and it works for some test strings like `x=(1+2))+3` is false, `x=((1+2))+3` is true, `x=()((1+2))+3` is true and `x={[((1+2))]+3}` is als true. By the way you should remove the `System.out.println(operatorStack.pop());` if you use `pop()` instead of `peek()` inside the `if` statements, because the additional `pop()` removes another character from your stack.

Comment: Tom- Are you sure. coz i have been trying that, and i am still having error.

Comment: can you try to edit the code for me in the top ?

Comment: Do you have an error like an exception? Or just wrong test results? Look at my answer. It might help you.

Comment: Just wrong answer!- I am getting that expression as true.

Comment: How should this comment help? You're unable to tell you problem and you're unable to provide an expression that won't work correctly. And please don't point to the above expression again. It does work. ... edit: I'm getting it as false. Have you tried my code instead of yours? Are there differences? If not, try use Stack instead of your current type of stack.

Comment: I have been trying again and again. I can't figure out whats wrong. it doesn't work again.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/vUHQ3AxD    This is my code now

Comment: If I use that code and replace `operatorStack.isStackEmpty()` with `operatorStack.isEmpty()` (keep in mind that I use a different type of stack) it also works like mentioned in my answer. Can you try to use `Stack` instead of your current stack type?

Comment: Also check that the variable `infix` is what you think it is. Add `System.out.println(infix);` before the `for` loop inside the method `checkEquation`.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3fcvdotuuxwid5v/Screenshot%202014-09-13%2023.14.04.png?dl=0   check this -TOM

Comment: Now we are talking ;). I also had a `true` in the second line, but this can be easily fixed. The problem is that you don't clear the stack before doing the check. That means if you have a remaing `(` (see the test before) it will be used in the next check. I edited my answer to mention that.

Comment: I don't see what changes you did to get the answer

Comment: I added the line `operatorStack.clear();` at the beginning of the method `checkEquation`.

Comment: Oh! Thanks man, appreciate all your help!

Comment: We may should think about cleaning up here :D. I guess we can delete all comments except your `code-apprentice: tried with debugger, but couldn't come up with a solution.` comment.

Comment: One more thing though, shouldnt be the clear() method inside for loop? why is it outside?

Comment: If it is inside the loop you will clear it in every iteration step. That way no stored character will survive an iteration. Therefore you can't check them later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the changed code that works for my samples. See the added comments for the changes.

```
public static Scanner input;
public static Stack<Character> operatorStack;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    operatorStack = new Stack<>(); // <- I used Stack, because I don't know what kind of stack you used
    System.out.println(checkEquation("x=(1+2))+3"));        
    System.out.println(checkEquation("x=((1+2))+3"));
    System.out.println(checkEquation("x={[((1+2))]+3}"));
    System.out.println(checkEquation("x=()   ()   ()"));
    System.out.println(checkEquation("x=()   )(   ()"));
    System.out.println("-----");
    System.out.println(checkEquation("x=((1+2)*3"));
    System.out.println(checkEquation("x=(1+2))*3"));
    System.out.println(checkEquation("x=(z*j)/(b*8)^2"));
    System.out.println(checkEquation("x=((p*2)"));
}

public static boolean checkEquation(String infix) { // <- don't mind that "static". You don't need that
    operatorStack.clear(); // <- clear the stack to remove old data
    for (int j = 0; j < infix.length(); j++) {

        // check for opening parentheses omitted

        else if (infix.charAt(j) == ')') {
            if (operatorStack.isEmpty()) { // <- different check for empty stack (due to the different stack type)
                // System.out.println(operatorStack.pop()); // <- removed unwanted pop() call
                return false;
            }
            if (operatorStack.pop() != '(') { // <- changed from peek() to pop()
                // System.out.println(operatorStack.pop());
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (infix.charAt(j) == ']') {
            if (operatorStack.isEmpty()) { // <- different check for empty stack (due to the different stack type)
                return false;
            }
            if (operatorStack.pop() != '[') { // <- changed from peek() to pop()
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (infix.charAt(j) == '}') { 
            if (operatorStack.isEmpty()) { // <- different check for empty stack (due to the different stack type)
                return false;
            }
            if (operatorStack.pop() != '{') { // <- changed from peek() to pop()
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return operatorStack.isEmpty();
}
```

The test result is:

```
false
true
true
true
false
-----
false
false
true
false
```

If you find an expression that doesn't work, feel free to add a comment.